# How can I create an exe from a Python Script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, pyinstaller, pyarmor

I'm trying to create a python script that generates an exe. But I'd like to have it run so that the user doesn't need to have python installed to run the script. This is my code: (This has been converted to an exe using pyinstaller)

```
import os

with open('output.py', 'w') as writeout:
     writeout.write('''
Hello world!
''')

# Creates pyinstaller by using cmd
os.system('cmd /c' + ' pyinstaller --onefile' + output + '.py')
```

So my code is basically an exe that generates an exe. But the problem is that a user will need Python installed to run this exe (the original one). Since all this code does is write out `pyinstaller --onefile output.py` in cmd. I read pyinstaller's documentation but I didn't find anything useful.

Comment: If you convert the basic script to an exe, and distribute the exe, the user doesn't need to have python installed.  The way you seem to want to do it, as shown above, the user needs python installed to create the exe.  What am I missing?

Comment: Yes but the original script will end up using cmd to generate another exe. So basically it's an exe that creates another exe. And to access cmd and use the command ```pyinstaller --onefile output.py``` the user will need both python and pyinstaller installed

Comment: delete the last two lines from your script, use pyinstaller to create an exe and distribute the exe

Comment: How will that work tho? How will it generate the exe?

Comment: See the Pyinstaller documentation at http://www.pyinstaller.org